# Visual Studio: "Break when an exception is thrown" option gets reset randomly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, exception

I like to have VS break on any thrown CLR exception so I tick the corresponding box in Debug -> Exceptions.

[image: Dialog]

But a couple of times a day this option seems to get reset to 'disabled' randomly, so I have to go there and check it again. Any ideas?

Comment: Please someone answer this - I have the exact same question!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed when the solution file (aka "projectsname.**suo**") gets deleted, the Break on  exceptions gets reset.